# Using Query to change Absolute Values to positive or negative values based on whether a separate column is one of 4 options

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, currency

I have my checkbook through Google Sheets. It is linked to a form so that I can have it offline, type in the details of a transaction, and then it puts it into the sheet and depending on which bank account it is, it then puts it onto the respective sheet. I have been unable to figure out how to get a query function to show whether any particular transaction is positive or negative based on another column in the sheet. This other column would show whether the transaction amount column should be negative or positive.

Part of the form asks whether it is a "Withdrawal" (Spending money), a "Deposit" of money, a "Transfer" from one account to another, or a "Payment" of a card using either the checking or savings accounts.
I would like to be able to make an entry in to the form, without having to remember to write -X for a Withdrawal and (+)X for a Deposit, and so on. So, merely writing the Absolute Value, and having the sheet calculate whether it is positive or negative to that account.
I also would like to be able to record a credit card payment as a "Withdrawal" from the Checking or Savings account, and a "Deposit" onto the credit card.

I am fairly new to query functions, and have tried to do research on if a query can in any way include an If or Ifs Function, but have found no success.

Sheet "Form Response"

- Column B = Account in Question
- Column C = "Withdrawal", "Deposit", "Transfer", or "Payment"
- Column D = In instances of transfers or payments, this is the account where the money is going
- Column E = The transaction amount. Will be an absolute value.
- Column F = Transaction Description
- Cell A2 = Cell with Account name in question

Essentially, in my mind,

=query('Form Responses'!$B$G, "Select F,E,G [where B contains '"&A2&"'or D contains '"&A2&"'] and C Contains 'Deposit'" OR "Select F,E*-1,G [where B contains '"&A2&"'or D contains '"&A2&"'] and C Contains 'Withdrawal'",0)

This still would not even account for the Transfers and Payments, which could be combined into just Transfers if needed.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z2uQRs5bSIRv327uSgpmAIdizL3wWPLD8uWLPtsQgRE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added formula to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z2uQRs5bSIRv327uSgpmAIdizL3wWPLD8uWLPtsQgRE/edit#gid=1346449485). Please do test it out.

```
=lambda(a,b,c,d,e,f,
        filter({f,ifs((b=A$2)*(c="Deposit"),e,b=A$2,-e,d=A$2,e,TRUE,""),a},(b=A$2)+(d=A$2)))
('Form Responses'!$A:$A,'Form Responses'!$B:$B,'Form Responses'!$C:$C,'Form Responses'!$D:$D,'Form Responses'!$E:$E,'Form Responses'!$F:$F)
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to work beautifully with every example I can throw at it. Thank you so much, that is amazing. I've not even heard of a lambda function prior to this, and now I want to learn all about how to use them.

Comment: Would it be possible to sort them by the date in Column G, instead of the date in Column A?

Comment: you just have to change this part of the formula from `'Form Responses'!$A:$A` to `'Form Responses'!$G:$G`